# 100% Height on LI

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How can I obtain to get LI's 100 % in height, just like this: [image: 100% Height on LI]

As you can see, the borders on the LI elements are 100 % in height.

Currently I have this:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column grid_13" style="padding-top:5px;">
            <div class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="images/logosmall.png"></a></div> 
        </div><!-- End Grid_3 -->

        <ul class="headerMenu">
            <li>Profile</li>
            <li><img src="images/icons/arrow-down.png" style="vertical-align:middle;"></li>
        </ul>


    </div><!-- End Row -->
</div><!-- End Header -->
```

This is my CSS. Please note I have not added the "Row" and the "column" or "grid" sections in the CSS, as they are just normal GRID's from 960.css

```
.header{
    background-image:url("../images/headerstyle.png");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
   /* height:50px; */
    height:60px;
    border-color:#000;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-style:solid;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px #232323;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px #232323;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px #b6b6b6;

}
.headerMenu{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
.headerMenu li{
    display:inline;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color:#fff;
    border-color:#086c8a;
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    height:100%;  
}
```

Comment: Does the enclosing UL have any padding?

Comment: The enclosing? The UL class is .headerMenu, and it have padding:0

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish.  From the code snip it looks like you are mimicking a table with divs and one row and then trying to have an unordered list in that rows.    Are you wanting the UL to have 100% height of the  <div class="row"> element?

Comment: sorry for that meta question, but where's that screenshot from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example with no link style but this is how I do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/ZVXFD/1/

Make sure the ul have no pading and margin and the same height as the header. After create the li the same height as the ul and header.

Comment: word of advice, jsfiddle has a panel for css, you dont have to put the css in the html panel

Answer (score 11):

The `height: 100%` on you li tags doesn't work because you specified `display: inline`. You can't set the height of an inline element.

You'll either have to use `display: inline-block` or `float: left` for this to work.

Note that `display: inline-block` only works on native inline elements in IE6-7, so it won't work with li tags in those browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tonco/UrhTw/2/

```
<div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item">     
            Test height<br />
            size
        </li>
        <li class="sep">     
            <b></b>
        </li>
        <li class="item">     
            Test height<br />
            size
        </li>
        <li class="sep">     
            <b></b>
        </li>
        <li class="item">     
            Test height<br />
            size
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
.list{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;   
}

.item{
    padding: 5px;
    background: red;
}

.sep{
    width: 1px;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    background: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The JS fiddle is a broken link.

Answer (score 1):

`display: table-cell;` on the `LI` might help

Answer (score 0):

you could use

> display: inline-block

it’s a way to make elements inline, but preserving their block capabilities such as setting width and height, top and bottom margins and paddings.

There is more info on the pros and cons of **inline-block** [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) including ways to get it  working in IE7 using MS's **zoom** property.